# Using custom ListView adapter with default Android themes

Tags: android, listview, themes, adapter

I'm developing an app on Honeycomb with a ListView. When using a normal ArrayAdapter to feed the ListView content, I can pass it a built-in layout such as [Android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html#simple_selectable_list_item). This creates a clickable item with a nice fading animation when selecting an item that is consistent with the overall Honeycomb feel.

However, if I decide to use my own custom layout (or to create a custom adapter), I no longer have any animation when focusing on or selecting an item in the ListView. I could construct my own animation, but I would prefer to use the default Holo theme when developing for Honeycomb for simplicity and consistency.

I'm at a loss for how to do this and haven't been able to find anyone else with my struggle (perhaps I'm searching the wrong terms, or am missing something obvious!). Does anyone have any suggestions? I figure it involves identifying some sort of style or theme in the XML file for the layout, but I haven't figured out where to put that or what the contents might be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Got it: I had to remove *all* references to android:listSelector and android:background for my ListView. Then I added

```
android:background=?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator
```

to my top-level view for the ListView row layout.

Comment: ListView selector is drawn by a ListView under the currently touched item. When your items have a non transparent background (which they shouldn't have) you obvoiusly can't see that. You just draw a background of an item and a list draws it's selector beneath it introducing unnecessary overdraw. Bear in mind that if you absolutely need a non transparent item background a list can draw selectors on top (android:drawSelectorOnTop). Just some food for thought.